# Find visible items in bound WPF Datagrid from MVVM controller

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I have a custom datagrid (implements `ICollectionView`) and a datasource (`ICollectionSource`). The grid is obviously bound to that source.
When a filter is applied to the grid, I would liek to access the items that are visible in the grid.

How do I do that in an MVVM environment where I do not have access to the view (i.e. the grid instance)?

Would the view or viewmodel need to create a distinct collection of items that are not filtered out? I do not quite understand how that would work.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. The BookLibrary.Applications / Controllers / BookController class contains the method “RemoveBook”. This method retrieves the BookCollectionView so that it gets the filtered/sorted collection from the DataGrid. All this is done by following the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I looked at that project, specifically the ICollectionView. I don't see where it shows the visible items... granted if you had a fixed size grid you could probably calculate it based on the selected item, but what about when the grid is resizable?